# Convert comma formatted string to number jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to convert the string into number.`33,320.04`
code snippet as follow

```
var x=$('#totalPrice').val();//here comes 33,320.04
if(x>5000){do my job}
```

how to do it?

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: Please edit your quetsion with your expected output.

Comment: compare x with some values like greater than 5000 or less than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format is always like that, you could just replace the ',' with the empty string:

```
var x=parseFloat($('#totalPrice').val().replace(/,/g, ""))
```

Comment: what does replace(/,/g, "")) mean?

Comment: It globally replace all `,` with `''`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use like this

```
var array = string.split(',');
```

this will be treated as an array, this is the possibility, also you can use

```
 .replace(/,/g,'"')
```

Comment: you change the `,` to an `"`, that makes no sence, pls test your code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="33,320.04";
var x= parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g,''));
if(x>5000){
    alert("x is greater");
}
else
{
    alert("x is smaller");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1w7uh68b/)**